# Format multiple type of date string into a same date format on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, json, datetime

I'm currently having an issue getting data from SQL Server and changing it into mySQL with DATETIME field type.

The thing is this, I receive a JSON with SQL data and decode it, then I run a foreach to get all data from JSON, on previous questions I validate if fields weren't empty, but right now I have a problem formatting DATETIME strings, I don't have all code but here is the deal:

```
$datefromsql = '01/04/2015';//on SQL DB is 2015-04-01 00:00:00
$datefromsql = '01/04/2015 12:20:00';//this on SQL DB is 2015-04-01 12:20:00
```

I don't know why when JSON is contructed the date format comes as the variable I declared, the thing is mySQL only admits Y-m-d H:i:s and searching they don't admit other formats. I tried the following

```
$dateformysql = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $datefromsql), 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

but when they don't have hours it doesn't just get the date but inserts 0 on all. How could I do this?

Fields on mySQL and SQL are DATEFORMAT type, the thing is dates are coming on both ways and since I can't modify how data comes, I need to rework it on PHP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try :

```
$dateformysql = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($datefromsql));
```

Comment: It works good for now :) Now I have to test it if it works on all fields, but maybe could you tell me why my code doesn't work?